# Использование кириллицы в поиске в mySQL

Tags: mysql, кириллица

Реализовывал поиск по mySQL, пока не столкнулся с проблемой невозможности поиска с использованием кириллицы.

```
$str = '%'.$_GET['s'].'%';
$pdo = new PDO(подключение);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id LIKE ? OR order_id LIKE ? OR datetime LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($str, $str, $str, $str));
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    $clients[] = $row['id']."|".$row['order_id']."|".$row['datetime']."|".$row['name'];
}
```

Возникает ошибка Illegal mix of collations for operation ‘like’. Пробовал также добавлять, но ничего не дало.

```
datetime LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

В настройках mySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Использование datetime обязательно, но ошибки возникают именно с ним.
Прошу подсказать, как можно исправить ошибку :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629094/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-like-while-searching-with-ignited-data  все дело в `datetime` наверное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в вопросе указано, что это происходит из-за datetime :) Ссылку уже видел ранее, предположил, что решение уже есть.

Comment: я что-то не увидел просто это сообщение про `datetime` Тогда дело тут не в кириллице.. может тогда следует предварительно проверить что там в гет запросе и от этого либо исполнить запрос без `datetime` либо сконкатенировать его к зпросу

Comment: А вопрос такой. Причем тут кириллица ,если у вас там в запросе манипуляции сплошные с цифрами? Проверяйте `GET` на наличие необходимых вам  символов. Типа если не число - то не выполнять ничего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не все столбцы приведены в коде, есть и несколько кириллических. Три указал для примера. Подскажите, на какие символы проверять входную строку ($_GET) ?
P.S. Изменил вопрос (добавил четвертый текстовый столбец)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать проверить параметр `GET` на число и в зависимости от этого проводить остальные действия.
Но, скорее всего, придется разделить логику на два разных запроса. Как минимум потому, что если это число, значит поиск по имени точно бесполезно делать, что будет только лишней нагрузкой.

Тем более при способе `LIKE %SEARCH_STRING%` индексы таблицы в БД не используются.

Аналогично, если поиск будет не числом, тогда делать в запросе `LIKE` по числам - бестолково.

Пример:

```
$str = '%'.$_GET['s'].'%';
$getIsNumeric = is_numeric($_GET['s']) || is_numeric(strtotime($_GET['s'])); // выдаст true если придет id или datetime

$pdo = new PDO(подключение);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name LIKE ?";

if (!$getIsNumeric) {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($str));
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id LIKE ? OR order_id LIKE ? OR datetime LIKE ?"
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($str, $str, $str));
}

while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    $clients[] = $row['id']."|".$row['order_id']."|".$row['datetime'];
}
```

Вообще, как мне кажется, поиск по `id` выглядит странным. Думаю, это потенциально может быть причиной взлома. Так как я, как взломщик могу знать, что Вася Пупкин имеет `id` 111, это облегчает способ взлома.
`order_id` тоже.

Не уверен, что поиск по данным полям является правильным решением. 
Стоит поискать информацию на данную тему на всякий случай.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку с разделением числовых и текстовых значений. ID нужно использовать, тем более поиск доступен только администрации.

Comment: @endless ну да. админам еще можно. но только осторожно)) я это хотел дописать. главное обычным юзверям это не давать